# Jquery mobile panel error

Tags: jquery-mobile, panels

On my site http://www.mobile-development.org each page has a different panel which you can open using the header.  Only the first page has a link instead of a panel. When I navigate to a course page and then back to home and do this twice then I get an error when I open the course information page.

It is a difficult problem which is also difficult to explain. Hopefully someone can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by deleting the panel of the page with the problem. It is a workaround but at least is it working now smoothly.